# Finding value of $\lim _{n\to\infty} \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin x}{1+\cos^2(nx)}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

We have to calculate $$\lim _{n\to\infty} \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin x}{1+\cos^2(nx)}dx$$
Now I thought that perhaps the integral needs to be calculated in terms of $n$ and then we plug in the limit but I could find no way to do it.

Perhaps it is non-integrable as an indefinite integral but I couldn't find any way to do this even as a definite integral. I observed the fact that the integrand is an even function but even that just serves to reset the limits of the integral.

So now I'm completely stuck. I think Sandwich theorem may be used by establishing two estimates for the integral which are close to the integrand but I'm not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why the limit even exists...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Can you please elaborate?

Comment: ??? I don't know how to "elaborate" on that - I don't see why the limit exists.

Comment: If somehow proven not to exist this would be the answer, IMO.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: the limit exists as shown in the original (of which this is duplicate).

Comment: Another answers are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/683056) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2779392)